# PHP path for script making function call

Tags: php, dirname

I have a helper file that basically looks like this:

```
helper.php:
<?php
  function renderPartial($name) {
    return file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/'.$name.'.php');
  }
```

And I'm trying to call that function from within a view:

```
view.php:
<h2>Title</h2>
<?= renderPartial('_form') ?>
```

_form.php is in the same directory as view.php, so I want to search in that directory.  The __DIR__ magical constant returns the directory of helper.php instead of view.php.  Any way to include a helper file like that and return the directory of the file making the call instead of the file where the function is defined?  I've searched through the PHP documentation, and I can't find any constants or helper functions.

Comment: what directory is `helper.php` in?

Comment: you should do a `include`, or `require', instead of just reading the `.php` file... in that way you can `send variables` through your script(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass the current `__DIR__` as an argument

```
function renderPartial($name, $dir) {
    return file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$name.'.php');
}
```

and

```
<?= renderPartial('_form', __DIR__) ?>
```